# Why do some programs' processes exist after forking a child, without the child starting a new process session?

Tags: linux, bash, process, session

Here are some of the steps for creating a daemon process from a given process,

- the given process exists soon after forking a child,
- the child calls start a new session and  also a new group, by `setsid()`

But I seem to find cases with only the first step without the second step:

- [in a login session under a desktop environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490249/how-does-altf2-run-a-command-as-child-of-the-init-process)
- [in an interactive bash process.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491157/does-sleep-123-remove-the-process-group-from-bashs-job-control)

What is the purpose of only having the first step without the second step?

Does it not want to create a daemon but something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose, on high level, is best seen in the bash example that you gave. When, in an interactive bash shell, a normal user types `ls`, what happens is

- Bash forks
- the child process execs `ls`
- when `ls` is finished, the child process ends

It would be silly to daemonize `ls`, because (in general) it ends very quickly.

Furthermore, it would also be strange is all processes that are forked from a shell would do a `setuid()`. You would then not be able to run a shell as a normal user.

Do not take the specifics of daemons as the general rule for the use of fork/exec.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't ask   how a shell executes an external command in general.

Comment: The point is in the last sentence: you seem to take the process of daemonisation as the norm.

Comment: I didn't. Please reread my post.

Comment: "Does it not want to create a daemon but something else?" The answer then is "something else". I also noticed that you changed `setuid()` in your question to `setsid()`, which makes my remark about `setuid()` no longer applicable.

Comment: That's my typo.